# SpringsourceTool Suite 2.9.2: Complaining about groovy-all-1.8.6.jar missing for UNUSED grails 2.0.3 installation

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am frustrated beyond words.  I upgraded to STS 2.9.2 in hopes of getting away from the plethora of issues I experienced with 2.9.1.  Now it seems the problems are even worse.

In addition to the jline_.dll issue, which keeps raising its ugly head (and for which the only solution I've found is to quit STS, delete the .ivy-cache, and restart STS), now I can't even run any of my projects, due to some bizarre error about not finding groovy-all-1.8.6.jar.

```
The archive: C:/springsource/**grails-2.0.3**/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
```

BUT - all of my projects are configured for grails 2.1.0!?!?

Where do I need to look to find this rogue reference to grails 2.0.3?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, after much searching. The error was reporting that grails 2.0.3 jar was being referenced, although of course, this was not the set preference in any active projects. I hunted through all the preferences and .project files. Did not find anything.

Then I saw files in the .metadata:

```
./plang1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/planG (run-app).launch:<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot
; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/springsource/grails-2.0.3/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/g
roovy-all-1.8.6.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
./plang1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/planG (run-app).launch:<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot
; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/springsource/grails-2.0.3/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.0.3.jar&quot; pat
h=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
./plang1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/planG-Admin (run-app).launch:<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-
8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/springsource/grails-2.0.3/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/
jars/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
./plang1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/planG-Admin (run-app).launch:<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-
8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/springsource/grails-2.0.3/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.0.3.jar&quo
t; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
./plang1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/planG-Admin .launch:<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; s
tandalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/springsource/grails-2.0.3/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groo
vy-all-1.8.6.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
./plang1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/planG-Admin .launch:<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; s
tandalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/springsource/grails-2.0.3/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.0.3.jar&quot; path=&
quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
./plang1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.search/dialog_settings.xml:                     <item value="/springsource/grails-2.0.3/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-a
ll/jars/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar" key="textPattern"/>
```

with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="com.springsource.sts.grails.core.launchconfig">
<stringAttribute key="com.springsource.sts.grails.core.ORG_SCRIPT" value="run-app"/>
<stringAttribute key="com.springsource.sts.grails.core.PROJECT_DIR" value="C:\workspaces\plang1\planG"/>
<stringAttribute key="com.springsource.sts.grails.core.SCRIPT" value="run-app"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.appendEnvironmentVariables" value="true"/>
<mapAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.environmentVariables">
<mapEntry key="GRAILS_STS_RUNNING" value="true"/>
</mapAttribute>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH">
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry containerPath=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.7.0&quot; path=&quot;2&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/springsource/grails-2.0.3/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/springsource/grails-2.0.3/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.0.3.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/lib/tools.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
</listAttribute>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.DEFAULT_CLASSPATH" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="planG"/>
<stringAttribute key="process_factory_id" value="com.springsource.sts.grails.core.processFactory"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

I shut down STS, deleted all the launch files, restarted STS, and voila, it worked.  No more runtime errors about the 2.0.3 jar file missing.

Comment: This also happened to me when I updated from Grails 2.0 to 2.1. I only had to delete the "run-app" launch config from GGTS 3.1 (variant of STS) and problem went away. No need to shutdown STS.